# Generic function for enum in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-generics

I have several enums and for each enum a function like this:

```
getMyEnumSelectItems(): Observable<SelectItem[]> {
    const values = Object.values(MyEnum);
    return this.translate
      .stream(values.map((val) => `myEnum.${val}`))
      .pipe(
        map((translatedValues) =>
          values.map((val) => ({ label: translatedValues[`myEnum.${val}`] || val, value: val }))
        )
      );
  }
```

I now would like to introduce a single generic function to handle all enums in the same way. What I need is something like this (pseudo code):

```
getSelectItems<T extends Enum>(): Observable<SelectItem[]> {
    const values = Object.values(T);
    const camelCaseName = nameof(T).toCamelCase();

    return this.translate
      .stream(values.map((val) => `${camelCaseName}.${val}`))
      .pipe(
        map((translatedValues) =>
          values.map((val) => ({ label: translatedValues[`${camelCaseName}.${val}`] || val, value: val }))
        )
      );
  }
```

The method call would be like follows: `const selectItems = getSelectItems<MyEnum>();`

Is there a way to get such a generic function?

Answer (score 2):

Making the function generic is the wrong approach here. Generic functions are only used when you want to create a *relation* between the types of parameters and the return type (or between individual parameters).

Furthermore, it is impossible to take a genric type `T` and do *anything* with it at *runtime*. Remember that types get erased during compilation which makes `Object.values(T)` not representable during runtime.

What you want to do instead is *pass* the `enum` to the function as an argument.

```
function getSelectItems(enum_: object): Observable<SelectItem[]> {
    const values = Object.values(enum_);
    const camelCaseName = nameof(enum_).toCamelCase();

    return this.translate
      .stream(values.map((val) => `${camelCaseName}.${val}`))
      .pipe(
        map((translatedValues) =>
          values.map((val) => ({ label: translatedValues[`${camelCaseName}.${val}`] || val, value: val }))
        )
      );
}
```

I typed `enum_` to be of type `Record<string, string | number>`. So technically any object of that shape can be passed to the function and it does not have to be an `enum`. But there isn't really anything in the type system which differentiates enums from other objects. So this is as good as it gets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I understood you correctly the function will not work as expected, because something like `nameof(enum_)` won't be possible - right?

Comment: @MatterOfFact - I think it is not possible to get the name of an enum. Both at compile time and at runtime.